# Retrieve data from same table where criteria is x mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that holds I and R dates under the Act column, so far so good I am able to get the duration_total but i am unable to get duration_before_issuing and processing_duration because all that data which determines that sits on one same table tracking, so i have a challange finding `where t.Act = I and t.Act = R` at the same time to give the result as shown in the last diagram. Any suggestions?

---

My SQL-Transact

```
SELECT  t.product, r.pro_name, r.d_date, t.Date,  DATEDIFF(t.Date, r.d_date) as duration_total
FROM tracking t, request r 
WHERE t.product = r.product
AND t.Act ='R'
```

tracking t

```
product | Act | Date
---------------------------
a       | I |    date-i
--------------------------
a       | R |    date-r
---------------------------
b       | I |    date-i
---------------------------
b       | R |    date-r
```

request r

```
product  | pro_name | d_date
------------------------------------------
a        | wacha    | date-d
------------------------------------------
b        | wewe     | date-d
```

Result

```
pro| pro_name      | duration_before_issuing    |  processing_duration |     duration_total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a  |  wacha  | t.Date(date-i)- r.d_date(date-d) | t.Date(R) - t.Date(I) | t.Date(R)- r.Date(r.d_date)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
b  |  wewe   | t.Date(date-i)- r.d_date(date-d) | t.Date(R) - t.Date(I) | t.Date(R)- r.Date(r.d_date)
```

Comment: You need to self join tracking table on itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to self join the tracking table on itself, selecting only the I records from one of them, and only the R records from the other.

```
SELECT t1.product, t2.date-r.d_date as duration_before_issuing, ... 
FROM tracking t1
INNER JOIN tracking t2 ON t1.product=t2.product
INNER JOIN request r ON t.product = r.product
WHERE t1.act='R' and t2.act='I'
```

Answer (score 1):

As Shadow commented, you need to join the tracking table twice. Something like:

```
SELECT  r.product, r.pro_name, r.d_date, 
DATEDIFF(t_issue.date, r.d_date) AS duration_before_issuing
DATEDIFF(t_done.date, t_issue.date) AS processing_duration
DATEDIFF(t_done.date, r.d_date) AS duration_total
FROM request r
INNER JOIN tracking t_issue ON r.product = t_issue.product AND t_issue.act='I'
INNER JOIN tracking t_done  ON r.product = t_done.product  AND t_done.act='R'
```

Note that I've made `request` the driving table of the query. I think that's a little clearer to read but it also helps if you need to handle the case where processing isn't yet complete. In that case you'd only have 1, or maybe 0 tracking dates for the request. The query above won't return a row for those requests. To fix that try using `LEFT JOIN` for one or both of the joins to `tracking`.  Or, you can use `UNION` to combine different queries that handle the different situations.